# How to get value of data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to grab html5 attribute values and have them match the value and attribute name with the class - then hide on click.

for example `data-table="sample11"` should hide `class="sample11"` same for `sample14` and any other attributes on this page

I was trying something like this but it isn't working for me - below is the way i am trying to do this - here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/xq6epy39/

Any help or guidance would be helpful. Thanks!

```
<div data-table="sample11">
  <a href="#">when i click this 'hide this' in sample11 should hide</a>
</div>

<div class="sample11">

  hide this
</div>


<div data-table="sample14">
   <a href="#">when i click this 'hide this' in sample14 should hide</a>
</div>

<div class="sample14">

  hide this
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var sample = $('div').data("table") === "11";

sample.click(function() {

  $('.sample11').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
$('div a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.' + $(this).parent().attr('data-table')).toggle();//hide()//slideToggle()//fadeToggle()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lor0md5/

Comment: thanks! what if the anchor tag is outside - for example ` http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/ca2175cz/ how can i make it work this way? @madalin ivascu

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ca2175cz/2/ seems cleanest.  Note that `e.preventDefault()` shouldn't be needed since the anchor is "#".

Comment: awesome!! thanks man. `[data-table]` works like a charm and easy to understand. thanks @RickHitchcock @madalin ivascu

Answer (score 0):

You can specify attributes using `[]`. There are several options using [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
var sample = $('div[data-table="11"]');

sample.click(function() {

  $('.sample11').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use data attribute with jquery. I have modified your code

```
<div>
   <a href="#" class="clickme" data-table=".sample14">when i click this 'hide this' in sample14 should hide</a>
</div>

<div class="sample14">

  hide this
</div>

$(".clickme").click(function(){
  alert($(this).data("table"));
  $($(this).data("table")).hide();
})
```

in place of hide you can call toggle function for hide/unhide.